# Windows Phone: PerformanceProgressBar not displayed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

Im using the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package. working on VS 2012 Pro.

The progress bar is not displayed even after making `NewProgressBar` Visible.

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      NewProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      CloudResponse res = await WebService.Instance.MailMessage();
      NewProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

      if (res.success == 1)
           MessageBox.Show("Message sent succesfully");
      else if (!res.errorMessage.IsEmpty())
           MessageBox.Show(res.errorMessage);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `IsEnabled` and `IsIndeterminate` properties of the progress bar are true.

Also u can take help from

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/b9755315-dd90-42f3-87be-0994415e8795/windows-phone-performance-progress-bar-not-getting-visible?forum=wpdevelop